# Appending table to tkinter from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I'm trying to append onto a table using tkinter by iterating through my list `championsList`.

```
# Grabbing Data
grab = championsList()
championList = dict(grab)
```

```
for champions in championList:
    championsTable.insert('', 'end', text="1",
                          values=(championList['Weight Class'], championList['Name']))

{'Weight Class': ['Bantamweight'], 'Name': ['Sterling, Aljamain']}
{'Weight Class': ['Featherweight'], 'Name': ['Volkanovski, Alex']}
{'Weight Class': ['Flyweight'], 'Name': ['Figueiredo, Deiveson']}
{'Weight Class': ['Heavyweight'], 'Name': ['Ngannou, Francis']}
{'Weight Class': ['Light_heavyweight'], 'Name': ['Teixeira, Glover']}
{'Weight Class': ['Lightweight'], 'Name': ['Oliveira, Charles']}
{'Weight Class': ['Middleweight'], 'Name': ['Adesanya, Israel']}
{'Weight Class': ['Welterweight'], 'Name': ['Usman, Kamaru']}
{'Weight Class': ['Womens_bantamweight'], 'Name': ['Pena, Julianna']}
{'Weight Class': ['Womens_featherweight'], 'Name': ['Nunes, Amanda']}
{'Weight Class': ['Womens_flyweight'], 'Name': ['Shevchenko, Valentina']}
{'Weight Class': ['Womens_strawweight'], 'Name': ['Namajunas, Rose']}
```

Gives the output:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: the data you have given is composed of multiple dictionaries, can you please either tell which you would like to show or change the variable to make it like a single multi dimensional array.

Comment: `tkinter` does't have any kind of `Table` widget, so it seems likely you're using some third-party module. Please identify what it is in your question (and add a tag for it if there is one) plus the code that is creating `championsTable` to it as well.